# WPF Base Grid Custom Control

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I had been using Windows Forms until now. I am working on a project on WPF now. In Windows Forms, I had created a Custom Grid Control by inheriting from Windows Grid and had added basic Events and Event Handlers for the common stuff. Also added a few Properties that could enable/disable these events being raised. And a lot more custom code like Styling etc.

I want to do the same in WPF. But I am not sure if this can be done. I am not able to do anything in XAML. And don't know how to bind default events (like adding a base/editable custom menu). Is that even possible?

Comment: Until and unless you are retemplating the whole control, there is no need to touch the default XAML. You can do all the required stuff in code as you have done for Winforms UserControl. In any case, it is not very clear what all things you have tried and what exactly isnt working for you. 'Not able to do anything' sounds too broad.

Comment: Please be more specific. For example styling you can do in xaml, and you do not need a custom control for that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I want to have the following abilities in the base grid:

1) Styles: I understand from your comment, that I should be creating a Styles.xaml for this. That resolves this.
2) Context menu: I want a context menu for basic functions like Export to Excel, Copy the Row etc etc.
3) Base Events with Handling: I don't want to write Export to Excel in every grid I add to my project. I want the base grid to take care of that.
4) Properties like Read-only.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in posting the reply. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.